Spark not asking for delegation tokens from ticket cache after upgrading to 3.5.1
We are not able to upgrade Spark from version 3.1.3 to 3.5.1 due to an authentication error.
Steps to reproduce the issue:

Create the Spark image from the binary.
Edit the image entrypoint in order to require a Kerberos ticket with a dedicated principal and keytab (kinit).
Execute the submit from other tools, such as Airflow.
The driver fails with the following error:

24/07/08 15:58:16 WARN Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:623)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:843)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:839)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1502)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:122)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy46.submitRequest(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy46.submitRequest(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.om.protocolPB.Hadoop3OmTransport.submitRequest(Hadoop3OmTransport.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.om.protocolPB.OzoneManagerProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.submitRequest(OzoneManagerProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:33
0)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.om.protocolPB.OzoneManagerProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.getServiceInfo(OzoneManagerProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:1
784)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.client.rpc.RpcClient.<init>(RpcClient.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.client.OzoneClientFactory.getClientProtocol(OzoneClientFactory.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.client.OzoneClientFactory.getRpcClient(OzoneClientFactory.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.BasicRootedOzoneClientAdapterImpl.<init>(BasicRootedOzoneClientAdapterImpl.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.RootedOzoneClientAdapterImpl.<init>(RootedOzoneClientAdapterImpl.java:51)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.RootedOzoneFileSystem.createAdapter(RootedOzoneFileSystem.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.BasicRootedOzoneFileSystem.initialize(BasicRootedOzoneFileSystem.java:189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1831)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileWriter.<init>(EventLogFileWriters.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.SingleEventLogFileWriter.<init>(EventLogFileWriters.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileWriter$.apply(EventLogFileWriters.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.<init>(EventLoggingListener.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2888)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1099)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount.main(JavaWordCount.java:43)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$submit$2(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
24/07/08 15:58:16 WARN Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:623)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:843)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:839)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1502)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:122)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy46.submitRequest(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy46.submitRequest(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.om.protocolPB.Hadoop3OmTransport.submitRequest(Hadoop3OmTransport.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.om.protocolPB.OzoneManagerProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.submitRequest(OzoneManagerProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:33
0)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.om.protocolPB.OzoneManagerProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.getServiceInfo(OzoneManagerProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:1
784)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.client.rpc.RpcClient.<init>(RpcClient.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.client.OzoneClientFactory.getClientProtocol(OzoneClientFactory.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ozone.client.OzoneClientFactory.getRpcClient(OzoneClientFactory.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.BasicRootedOzoneClientAdapterImpl.<init>(BasicRootedOzoneClientAdapterImpl.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.RootedOzoneClientAdapterImpl.<init>(RootedOzoneClientAdapterImpl.java:51)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.RootedOzoneFileSystem.createAdapter(RootedOzoneFileSystem.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.BasicRootedOzoneFileSystem.initialize(BasicRootedOzoneFileSystem.java:189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1831)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileWriter.<init>(EventLogFileWriters.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.SingleEventLogFileWriter.<init>(EventLogFileWriters.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileWriter$.apply(EventLogFileWriters.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.<init>(EventLoggingListener.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2888)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1099)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount.main(JavaWordCount.java:43)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$submit$2(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

The configurations (core-site.xml, hive-site.xml, Spark properties, etc) are exactly the same as the previous version, but in the driver log there are no requests for delegation tokens for the services listed in the property spark.kerberos.access.hadoopFileSystems or for Hive.
For example, in version 3.1.3 we have:
24/07/18 10:13:19 INFO HadoopFSDelegationTokenProvider: getting token for: RootedOzoneFileSystem{URI=ofs://xxx, workingDir=ofs://xxx/user/xxx, userName=xxx, statistics=0 bytes read, 0 bytes written, 0 read ops, 0 large read ops, 0 write ops} with renewer xxx
24/07/18 10:13:19 INFO KMSClientProvider: New token created: (Kind: kms-dt, Service: kms://https@xxx:9393/kms, Ident: (kms-dt owner=xxx, renewer=xxx, realUser=xxx, issueDate=1721297599498, maxDate=1721902399498, sequenceNumber=553, masterKeyId=128))
24/07/18 10:13:19 INFO HadoopFSDelegationTokenProvider: getting token for: S3AFileSystem{uri=s3a://xxx, workingDir=s3a://xxx/user/xxx, inputPolicy=normal, partSize=104857600, enableMultiObjectsDelete=true, maxKeys=5000, readAhead=65536, blockSize=33554432,...
...

This part is missing in version 3.5.1. There are additional properties that must be configured?
We tried to add the following properties for Spark:
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCreds=false
spark.kerberos.renewal.credentials=ccache

but with the same result.
